# SAPUI5 Formatter with visible form

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

could you help me for solve this issue ?
i have 2 or more field base on oData with different form. if i press with oData value (subty "1"), the result is true and oData (subty "2") is false.

then i press value "2", the result is true but value 1 is false

let' see my code :

in view, i write this code :
form 1
**

```
<f:SimpleForm visible="{path: 'Subty', formatter:'model.formatter.statusText'}"
 />
```

**

form 2
**

```
<f:SimpleForm visible="{path: 'Subty', formatter:'model.formatter.statusText1'}"
 />
```

*

in formatter, i write this code :

```
statusText: function (sStatus) {
                if (sStatus==="1"){
                     return "true";}
                if (sStatus==="2")
                {return "false";}
                else{
                    return "";
        }
    },
    statusText1: function (sStatus) {
                if (sStatus==="1"){
                     return "false";}
                if (sStatus==="2")
                {return "true";}
                else{
                    return "";
        }
    }
```

i have error with that code.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `visible` property is of type 'boolean' you will have to return a boolean value (true|false) in your formatter!

Please note:

```
"true" !== true
typeof "true" !== "boolean"
"false" !== false
typeof "false" !== "boolean"
typeof "" !== "boolean"
```

BR
Chris